# Why was the past perfect used before and after ‘since’?

Tags: past-tense, perfect-constructions, since

Can you please explain the use of two perfect tenses in one sentence with 'since'? The sentence is original and is taken from R.J. Palacio's book 'Wonder'

> "It had been a long time since I'd been out without my hearing aids, and it felt like I was miles under the earth."

According to traditional rules we would have to use past simple after 'since'? Is that any special case?

Comment: Where did you learn your "traditional rules"? This is the past perfect tense, which you can also use with *since*.

Comment: Take any grammar book and you'll find out that 90% of them do not explain the use of past perfect after since. Would you offer a better grammar book where I can read this rule&

Comment: I can't easily search grammar books with Google, but [The Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/since) does say that you can of past perfect after "since".  In this case, you need the past perfect after "since" because the main clause is in the past perfect.

Comment: Yes, I saw that example in the Cambridge Dictionary but it's really difficult to understand the meaning of two past perfects together as the basic meaning implies that the action in the past perfect is viewed as prior one to another action in the past.

Comment: @Natalie: you would put all the verbs in one sentence in the past perfect to show they happened **before** a verb in another sentence.

Comment: In case with two separate sentences I agree. Thanks a lot for your patience!

Comment: But you can also use the past perfect after since in sentences like *Since I had never seen him before, and he looked dangerous, I didn't let him in.*

Comment: here 'since' is not the conjunction of time. The meaning is 'because'. it's the clause of reason. This sentence is quite clear to me.

Comment: In my opinion, the "past perfect" is misnamed, and is not in any way a "perfect" construction. It is simply a "past in the past", or more explicitly, a "past looking back from a later time in the past", and doesn't (necessarily) have any of the special meanings or restrictions of the "present perfect". _I had been out_ is a backshifted from of both _I went out_ and _I have been out_ - the distinction between them is lost in this form.

Comment: @ColinFine - It's "perfect" from the Latin *perfectum* for "completed".  In this case it is *plus quam perfectum* or "pluperfect" - the time at which the action was completed is not only now but at some point in the past.   "Backshifting" is when we move the time frame back in summarizing reported speech, and it only applies to reported speech.

Comment: @BadZen, you're falling into the [etymological fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy): [_perfect_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)) denotes a particular aspect (different from _perfective_, by the way). And the fact that "backshifting" is customarily applied to reported speech does not prevent its being used in other cases. If I say _I had been out_ in a narrative, that implies that if I had been talking at the time I could have said _I went out_ or _I have been out_, but it does not specify which one of those I would have said.

Comment: What exactly do you dispute that I wrote?  I did not say "perfective", so that is a straw-man, why even mention it?.   "Perfectum", in Latin, was a grammar term that specifically referred to the tense aspect which we now call "perfect" in English, and the English word derives from the Latin word (just as the English word 'pluperfect' derives from the Latin phrase 'plus quam perfectum').   Where is the "fallacy"?

Comment: On the other hand, "backshifting" in English certainly refers only to reported speech.   Look in a grammar text book or do a Google search and see what you come up with for that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no need for replacing it with the past simple, or for providing any alternatives.

*Note that if you try to backshift the initial, present-time sentence you will get this one.*

> "It *had been* a long time since *I'd been* out without my hearing
> aids, and it felt like I was miles under the earth."

The mixture of tenses, or however you would like to call it, is used correctly.

It doesn't bear some specific meaning in comparison *with the past simple in the "since" clause.*

But to my ear, I suppose the speaker didn't intend to use the past simple because he could not remember the exact time of the action. That said, the clause implies *- unspecified time -*

I hope this answer helps you clear up your confusion :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand!

Comment: I don't understand what "initial, present-time sentence" you've "backshifted".   Your sentence is word-for-word identical with the use in the question.  And there's not a mixture of tenses here.